# Vigenere Cipher: Having issues with

Tags: python-3.x, class, encryption

I was following a python Vigenere cipher tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxFObRNriUg) and one of the issues I'm having is that that I consistently get key errors (which is understandable) but I don't understand why the youtube tutorial didn't go over that. Considering I followed the tutorial word for word (apart from the modifications made to fit with the class format), I don't understand why my code is having problems and not his. Any help?

```
class VigenereCipher(object):
    def __init__(self, key, alphabet):
        self.key = key
        self.alphabet = alphabet
        self.letter_to_index = dict(zip(self.alphabet, range(len(self.alphabet))))
        self.index_to_letter = dict(zip(range(len(self.alphabet)),self.alphabet))
    
    def encode(self, text):
        encrypted = ''
        split_message = [text[i:i+len(self.key)] for i in range(0, len(text), len(self.key))]
        for each_split in split_message:
            i = 0
            for letter in each_split:
                number = (self.letter_to_index[letter] + self.letter_to_index[self.key[i]])
                encrypted += self.index_to_letter[number]
                i += 1  
                print (encrypted)
        return encrypted
    
    def decode(self, text):
        decrypted = ''
        split_cipher = [text[i:i+len(self.key)] for i in range(0, len(text), len(self.key))]
        for each_split in split_cipher:
            index = 0
            for letter in each_split:
                number = (self.letter_to_index[letter] - self.letter_to_index[self.key[i]])
                decrypted += self.index_to_letter[number]
                i += 1
        return decrypted
```

Comment: You need to define `number` `% len(alphabet)` like they do in the tutorial. That's what makes the index loop back to 0 when you go over the number of characters in the alphabet.

Comment: See 5:19 in the video you linked.